# How to apply vignette and vintage image filter in app

Tags: objective-c, iphone, swift, image-processing, uiimage

I want to apply vignette and vintage image filters on my image.

I followed [this sample code](https://github.com/esilverberg/ios-image-filters).

I have integrated black &white and sephia filters.This code also provides vignette image filter but it processes it very slow and also app gets crashed for some small images when applying this filter.

Please suggest me how to implement vignette and vintage image filters.
Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Suggestion 1: find a library that does what you want (via Google search?) and integrate that to your code. Suggestion 2: work out an algorithm for what you want and then write the code for it. Suggestion 3: Have a go at doing suggestion 1 and 2 and then post a SPECIFIC question related to a programming issue.

Comment: @NickBull yes already gone through suggestion1 and 2 thats why I have attached the link of the example that I followed.If you know something about implementing these filters, please help.

Comment: @Warren I think that this question is pretty concrete, the vignette effect is a part of almost every vintage photo effect and no-one yet answered that question on stack as I know ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can do that fairly easily using [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage) and its GPUImageSepiaFilter and GPUImageVignetteFilter:

[image: Sepia and vignette filtered image]

The above image was generated using the following code:

```
UIImage *inputImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Lambeau.jpg"];

GPUImagePicture *stillImageSource = [[GPUImagePicture alloc] initWithImage:inputImage];
GPUImageSepiaFilter *stillImageFilter = [[GPUImageSepiaFilter alloc] init];
GPUImageVignetteFilter *vignetteImageFilter = [[GPUImageVignetteFilter alloc] init];
vignetteImageFilter.vignetteEnd = 0.6;
vignetteImageFilter.vignetteStart = 0.4;

[stillImageSource addTarget:stillImageFilter];
[stillImageFilter addTarget:vignetteImageFilter];
[stillImageSource processImage];

UIImage *filteredImage = [vignetteImageFilter imageFromCurrentlyProcessedOutput];
```

There's also a GPUImageGrayscaleFilter, if you wish to apply a grayscale filter to the source image.

As the framework name indicates, this is all GPU-accelerated, so it's far faster than any CPU-bound image processing routines. In fact, you can apply the above filters to live video. An iPhone 4 can run this filter in ~2 ms for 640x480 video frames. Still images are a little slower, due to the round trip through Core Graphics required when going to and from UIImages, but this is still up to 6X faster than CPU-bound filters.

One caveat with the current implementation is that non-A5 devices (iPhone 3G S, iPhone 4, iPad 1) have a texture size limit of 2048x2048, so I can't currently filter images larger than that. I'm working on a way to overcome this limitation, but in the meantime you might need to scale images down to fit within this resolution limit before processing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I will definitely try this.

Comment: @brad: Hi..i've used the same code in my project, but it says ""Property x not found on object type of GPUImageVignetteFilter" in the line 
vignetteImageFilter.x = 0.6;
And the same error for y

Comment: @Ajitthala - Those properties have changed names to vignetteEnd and vignetteStart. I've updated the code above to match, but you can find all this within the SimpleImageFilter example application.

Comment: `vignetteFilter.x = 0.4;` and `vignetteFilter.y = 0.6;`

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3**. Below the function to apply vintage effect. This function uses [Core Image](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/CoreImaging/ci_intro/ci_intro.html).

Use [Core Image Filters](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CoreImageFilterReference/index.html) to apply any effects for your image.

```
func processVintageImage(_ image: UIImage) -> UIImage {

    guard let inputImage = CIImage(image: image) else { return image }

    guard let photoFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIPhotoEffectInstant",
                                     withInputParameters: ["inputImage" : inputImage]),
        let photoOutput = photoFilter.outputImage,
        let sepiaFilter = CIFilter(name: "CISepiaTone",
                                   withInputParameters: ["inputImage": photoOutput]),
        let sepiaFilterOutput = sepiaFilter.outputImage,
        let vignetteFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIVignette",
                                      withInputParameters: ["inputImage": sepiaFilterOutput, "inputRadius" : 1.5, "inputIntensity" : 4.0]),
        let vignetteFilterOutput = vignetteFilter.outputImage else { return image }

    let context = CIContext(options: nil)

    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(vignetteFilterOutput, from: inputImage.extent)

    return UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
}
```